# Select data with a where clause on non-indexed column

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 103 columns and 10 million entries.

If I select data with a WHERE clause on non-indexed column, it spends a lot of time.

Below is an example of a query which spends 1m30s :

```
Select top 1 table_id from myTable where date is not null
```

it returns the id of the row number 9999995.

I tried to put a non clustered index on this non unique column but I didn't see any improvements

I would like to know if the processing time is normal. If not, is it due to the high number of columns defined in the data table (even if columns are mostly int, decimal and nvarchar(50) and datetime columns).

I would like to know if there is any recommandation that can improve the execution time?

Best regards.

Comment: `if I select data with a WHERE clause on non-indexed column, it spends a lot of time` doesn't it look like you know the answer?

Comment: As mentionned, adding an index on this column didn't solve the problem. Can this be explained by the fact that data defined in this column is not unique?

Comment: Show the code for index and execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

To make an answer that is of broader use than this specific question, I'm going to recommend using the [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx).

Basically, you can take your existing query and feed it to this tool, and it will chew on it for a while and spit out recommendations of indexes and statistics to create, along with estimated performance improvements.

In this case, you can feed it just your one query and get results (which will likely be just an index on the `[date]` field, as one of the comments to the OP stated).  But this tool can do so much more.  You can use it in conjunction with the [SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to capture a trace of all queries that hit your server, with optional filtering (i.e. execution time takes more than 1 second), and feed the entire trace to the Tuning Advisor.  The results of this approach are often so impressive in a production environment they appear to be magical to end users.

Here are a few handy links for getting started...

- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174202.aspx)
- [MSSQL Tips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/286/database-engine-tuning-advisor/)
- [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174202%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)